# how can I download file? ftp to my hard Drive use php

Tags: php, ftp, download

```
$local_file = 'C:\Users\mycom\Downloads\\'.$file_name;
$server_file = '/HDD1/'.$path.'/'.$file_name;

$ftp_user_name='user';
$ftp_user_pass='password';
$ftp_server='myserver.ipdisk.co.kr';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$source = "index.php";
$target = fopen("index.php", "r");

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$default_path = ftp_pwd($conn_id); 

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

i try this but don't work
I can see success message but I can't find download file

how can I do?

Comment: are you able to view the file using any FTP client & the above mentioned credentials ?

Comment: I found download file in a server.

Comment: What do you mean by "I found download file in a server." ? please clarify ?